# Email to Text not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, sms

I am trying to send an email as text to end users mobile, the code is running fine but I can't seems to get the SMS.

Here is my code

```
 public Task SendAsync()
    {
        var fromAddress = new MailAddress("test@gmail.com", "Authenticator");
        var toAddress = new MailAddress("mynumber@sms.sancharnet.in", "User");
        const string fromPassword = "mypassword";
        const string subject = "subject";
        string body = Session["PIN"].ToString();

        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
        };

        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body,
            IsBodyHtml = false
        })
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

Is there something I am missing here ? or is this not how we try to do an Email to text ?

Comment: You're not getting an SMS? Thought you send mails ;)
Are you getting an exception? Surround your code with a try catch clause and put a breakpoint in you catch block.

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier: Certain providers like Verizon offer a possibility to send an e-mails as a text message.

Comment: Have you configured your gmail account to allow you to send the mails?

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier yes I did

Comment: @MightyBadaboom I think I mentioned Email to Text ? Certain providers lets you do that. And yeah I tried that there is no exception as such.

Comment: Try using port 465 (SSL) instead of 587 (TLS).

Comment: If you're going to return a Task and name your method Async, then make use of async properly. use `smtp.SendMailAsync` and don't explicitly `return`.

Comment: @Odrai 465 is getting timed out.

Comment: two weeks ago I also tried gmail with smtp not worked they closed maybe I don't know try another mail account

Comment: I think the issue was with the service provider. I can make use of email to text only if I send an email from my sancharnet.in account nothing else works. Thanks for all the help guys, appreciated !